how to get current usage/cost for an Azure api service
I am using Azure map api service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/get-search-address?view=rest-maps-1.0&tabs=HTTP
It comes with a free tier usage limit, and above that, it is certain cost per 1000 transactions.
Is there any programatic way (like a rest api) to get the current usage or cost? I know that there is similar cost reporting functions in management console. But I want a programatic way of getting the cost/usage.
I looked into the Quota rest api provided by Azure, but that does not gives me a report on certain API usage.
Any links to some Azure apis that can achieve this will help. Thanks.

you should be able to use the cost management api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage?view=rest-cost-management-2024-08-01&tabs=HTTP

Thanks! I looked into it, looks very promising!

@Thomas, Thanks for the guidance! I looked into this cost api, and I got the cost as well. But looks like it is updated on daily basis. Is there a much real time monitoring apis? The last resort will be me implementing a database to keep a track on that myself, but I just want to see if there are existing real time tools. If not, still thanks for your help

not sure to be honest.

no worries! thank you

Thanks @Thomas and  I do agree that we can get the cost  using below rest api and I have followed Microsoft-Document:
The rest api is:
https://management.azure.com//subscriptions/1316/resourceGroups/rithwik/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/query?api-version=2024-08-01

In body you have to use filter.
$ril = "https://management.azure.com//subscriptions/1316/resourceGroups/rithwik/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/query?api-version=2024-08-01"
$aztkn = az account get-access-token --resource https://management.azure.com --query accessToken -o tsv
$ri_bd = @{
    type = "Usage"
    timeframe = "MonthToDate" 
    dataset = @{
        granularity = "Daily" 
        aggregation = @{
            totalCost = @{
                name = "PreTaxCost"
                function = "Sum"
            }
        }
        filter = @{
            dimensions = @{
                name = "ResourceId"
                operator = "In"
                values = @("/subscriptions/13f216/resourceGroups/rithwik/providers/Microsoft.Maps/accounts/rithmap") #Resource id
            }
        }
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
$ri_hd = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $aztkn"
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ril -Method Post -Headers $ri_hd -Body $ri_bd

Output:

if you expand properties you will get the cost.
